# Call to undefined method ConsoleTVs\Charts\Builder::new() laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am getting this error,Call to undefined method ConsoleTVs\Charts\Builder::new(), in my laravel version 5.5.22 when installing ConsoleTVs/Charts composer package. I have followed the tutorial properly and I don't see any part where I had gone wrong, I even use dump-autoload but nothing happen. Can anybody help me?  Thanks in advance

This is the link that I followed:
https://devhub.io/zh/repos/ConsoleTVs-Charts#pie

testController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Charts;

class PieController extends Controller
{
       public function index()
    {
        $chart = Charts::new('line', 'highcharts')
            ->setTitle('My nice chart')
            ->setLabels(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
            ->setValues([5,10,20])
            ->setDimensions(1000,500)
            ->setResponsive(false);
        return view('pie', ['chart' => $chart]);
    }
}
```

config/app.php

```
Providers:
  ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,

Aliases:
'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts::class,
or 
'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class,
```

pie.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>My Charts</title>

        {!! Charts::assets() !!}

    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            {!! $chart->render() !!}
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160124/discussion-on-question-by-dkna-call-to-undefined-method-consoletvs-charts-builde).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your issue, you need to remove the `setTitle()` and change it to `title()` instead, because this changed in new version!

The `Charts::new` has to be changed to `Charts::create` as the method `new` does not exist in the newer version. There is also the `Charts::database` if you want to get data from the database (more info in this link: https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-5-chart-example-using-charts-package)

The following command you need to run after installtaion:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

If you still get any error, then please follow this link and perform the steps as provide in it!: https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/issues/13

Hope this will fixed your issues!